# Can't log in to chat on some sites but can on SO

Tags: support, chat

I'm asking here, because I'm getting this problem on SuperUser, Electrical Engineering, Skeptics, ServerFault and Mathematics. The error I'm getting is "Your login data seems too old." I have no problems logging into SO chat. The [help](https://chat.stackexchange.com/help) link says that everything is fine.

I'm using Firefox 4.0.1 on Windows 7.

Comment: Have you tried [clicking **the button**?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/chat-stackexchange-login/)

Comment: @Yi Jiang Of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try logging out then logging back in again? (on any stackexchange.com site)

Beyond that see

https://chat.stackexchange.com/help

which is linked from

https://chat.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: Logging out and in solved the problem.